# Can't carry on with the installation of Elementary OS 6.1

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

When I go to install Elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir (i'm sure i didn't offend anyone with that spelling whatsoever) on Virtualbox 6.1.32, it only shows a quarter of the screen, and when i click enter, it does absolutely nothing.

Help???

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are seeing a screen something like this - in my case I had the problem with vmWare ESXi
[image: BootScreen Elemtary OS]

What you need to do is power down the guest, and then power it on again - but watch carefully - you'll get about 4 seconds to hit a key which brings up a Boot menu
[image: BootMenu]
If you press [Tab] as instructed, you'll get an editable command line  presented.  You need to add the option `vga=ask` at the end of the command and press Enter gently - you don't want to skip the next question.
[image: vga=ask]
Then press Enter gently again to reveal a list of screen resolutions
[image: Press Enter gently]
[image: List of screen resolutions]
I chose 336 [1280 x 1024] but probably 1024x768 will get you out of trouble.
[image: And there ya go]